# How is a statistic an observable random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variable, sample

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistic#Properties) says that a *statistic* is an *observable random variable*.

Now I think I know both what a statistic is, and what an observable random variable is.

#### What is a random variable?

A random variable is some measurable function.
Usually we implicitly assume that all random variables originate from the same sample space, so they can participate within the *same experiment*.
Observability doesn't matter much here.

An example of a random variable is the number of dots on the top face after a throw of a die.

#### What is a statistic?

Now, a statistic is some quantity that can be calculated **from a sample**. Formally we use the term "statistic" for both the algorithm/function that produces the value and the value itself.

A statistic can be the sum of of dots of ten die throws.
Here throwing one die is the "original experiment" that is repeated 10 times, maybe to estimate the mean of the number of dots that come out top.

#### How is a statistic a random variable?

Now, since a statistic is a function, further assuming measurability makes it a random variable.
But what is the domain of this function, e.g., to which sample space does it belong?
IMHO it is a function of the **sample**, which includes many draws from the "distribution of interest".
For the example, this means that the sum of dots of ten throws is a random variable for the experiment of throwing a die ten times.

But, usually I think of "observable random variables" as belonging to the "distribution of interest", i.e., throwing the die just once. And saying that a statistic is an "observable random variable" appears to be confusing, as a statistic is a random variable that belongs to a different sample space (the one that has the experiment of interest repeated).

#### So here are my questions

1. Is this observation correct?
2. How do you usually distinguish (in writing) between the "distribution of interest" and the sampling distribution, that has the experiment of interest repeated?
3. Is this confusing for everybody, or just for me?

Note: I came about this confusion while trying to understand the theorem of Rao-Blackwell (maybe the fifth time).

Comment: Adding a motivating example might help clarify your question.

Comment: @Scortchi I've added an example of throwing a die.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, in this example the domain of the statistic would be the sample space of the 10-dimensional random vector. The statistic itself is a random variable because it reduces the dimension (to 1).